# Combine region and second screen function with Sikulix

Tags: sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-ide, sikuli-x

I want Sikulix to search only in a certain region of my second screen.

So far my knowledge comes down to having either a part of my first (main) screen like:

`topLeft = Location(reg.x, reg.y)`

Or the whole second screen like:

`regscreen2 = Screen(2)`

Is there a way to specify part of monitor 2?

I can only imagine something like the code below but it doesn't work...:

`regiontopLeftScreen2 = topLeft.Screen(2)`

Answer (score 0):

Note that when you find a pattern on a screen, it returns `Match` object. Both, `Screen` and `Match` extend `Region` class which is the one that exposes all find methods. Hence, what you can do is just search within the resulting region just as you did with the screen.

For example:

```
Screen s = new Screen();
Match m = s.find("pattern1.png");
Match m1 = m.find("pattern2.png");
// etc...
```

Comment: thanks! all I had to do is o set the region in the new screen as I would in my normal screen.